# Convert byte array to hex string

Tags: ruby

I am trying to convert the following byte array to hexadecimal;

```
[1, 1, 65, -50, 6, 104, -91, -70, -100, 119, -100, 123, 52, -109, -33, 45, -14, 86, -105, -97, -115, 16]
```

The result should be;

```
010141CE0668A5BA9C779C7B3493DF2DF256979F8D10
```

Here is my current attempt;

```
item.getProperties["Mapi-Conversation-Index"].to_a.map {|s| s.to_s(16)}.join()
```

But my output is:  `010141-320668-5b-46-6477-647b34-6d-212d-e56-69-61-7310`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works:

```
[1, 1, 65, -50].map { |n| '%02X' % (n & 0xFF) }.join
```

The `%02X` format specifier makes a 2-character-wide hex number, padded with `0` digits.  The `& 0xFF` is necessary to convert your negative numbers into the standard 0 through 255 range that people usually use when talking about byte values.

Answer (score 14):

```
arr = [1, 1, 65, -50, 6, 104, -91, -70, -100, 119, -100, 123, 52, -109, -33, 45, -14, 86]

arr.pack("c*").unpack("H*").first
  #=> "010141ce0668a5ba9c779c7b3493df2df256"
```

See [Array#pack](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-pack) and [String#unpack](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-unpack).

The argument `"c"` for `pack` specifies an 8-bit signed integer. The argument `"H"` for `unpack` specifies "hex string (high nibble first)". The asterisk at the end of each directive specifies that `"c"` applies to all elements of `arr` and `"H"` applies to all characters of the string produced by `pack`.

Note that

```
arr.pack("c*")
  #=> "\x01\x01A\xCE\x06h\xA5\xBA\x9Cw\x9C{4\x93\xDF-\xF2V"
```

and

```
arr.pack("c*").unpack("H*")
  #=> ["010141ce0668a5ba9c779c7b3493df2df256"]
```

which is why `first` is needed to extract the string.

Comment: `arr.pack("c*").unpack1("H*")` can also be used