# Hash Conversion from Postgres to Rails

Tags: postgresql, hash

I am not sure what type of coded hash I am getting back from a postgres database that when queried shows instead a different code.

The question is...

how to convert this hash (as it is returned from Rails):

```
\x158\x06\xDB\xCD\x13M\xDE\xE6\x9A\x8CR\x04\xE3\x8A\xC8\x04H\xF6#B\xF8\xC2<\xFEK~\xDF
```

into this (as it shows inside the postgres database):

```
\x153806dbcd134ddee69a8c5204e38ac80448f62342f8c23cfe4b7edf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first hash (as you say, coming from Rails) is a byte array, in which any printable character is left as is instead of being converted to hex: `\x158` is really two characters: `'\x15'` and `'\x38'` (`'8'`).

In the Postgres table, that byte array is the same, but the format is to hexlify the whole thing.

So:

```
\x158\x06\xDB\xCD\x13M... is really \x15,8,\x06,\xDB,\xCD,\x13,M
-- becomes
\x153806dbcd134d... ('8':\x38, 'M':\x4d)
```

Comment: is there a way to hexify a byte array in Rails?

Comment: possibly, by adapting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50995539/758174).

Comment: for future reference [this](https://anthonylewis.com/2011/02/09/to-hex-and-back-with-ruby/) helped me